# Generating links in HTML

Tags: html, forms, href, datalist

I have a form with two `datalist` and I would like to generate a link based on the user's selection.

```
<form>

<input list="Cars">
  <datalist id="Cars">
  <option value="Honda" selected>Honda</option>
  <option value="Mazda">Mazda</option>
  <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
  <option value="Nissan">Nissan</option>
  <option value="Subaru">Subaru</option>
  </datalist>

<input list="Years">
  <datalist id="Years">
  <option value="2017">2017</option>
  <option value="2016">2016</option>
  <option value="2015">2015</option>
  </datalist>

  <input type="reset">

</form>
```

For an example, if user chooses Honda and 2017, then the link appears and the address is `Honda/2017.net`. If the user chooses Subaru and 2015 then the address is `Subaru/2015.net` and etc.

I can input the different `href` manually in the code but I am not sure how you make one link change based on selection?

Comment: You're going to need javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need Javascript for the so called dynamic html or DHTML. Could be done like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function generateLink()
{

  var brand = document.getElementById('carBrand').value;

  var year = document.getElementById('carYear').value;

  document.leform.action =brand + '/' + year + '.html';

  return true;

}
</script>

<form name="leform" onsubmit="return generateLink();">

<input list="Cars" id='carBrand'>
  <datalist id="Cars">
  <option value="Honda" selected>Honda</option>
  <option value="Mazda">Mazda</option>
  <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
  <option value="Nissan">Nissan</option>
  <option value="Subaru">Subaru</option>
  </datalist>

<input list="Years" id='carYear'>
  <datalist id="Years">
  <option value="2017">2017</option>
  <option value="2016">2016</option>
  <option value="2015">2015</option>
  </datalist>

  <input type="reset">
  <input type="submit">

</form>
```

What happens?

If the submit Button is clicked, the generateLink() function is called. `onsubmit="return generateLink();"`

In the generateLink() function the value of the selected option for the car/brand and the year are read from html using the `getElementById` function.

Then the extracted values for the brand and the year are used to generate the corresponding link via concatenation of car, a slash, the year and finally the string '.html'.

The link the form will redirect to is set in the forms action attribute. `document.leform.action`

To process data submitted by the form you will need some kind of CGI mechanism: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface
You could use PHP to pass data further to a database for example.

Hope this helps ^^-d

PS: You could also want to implement the page that follows the form (`action=`) in PHP as dynamic content. Using a HTTP GET Request this could look like /show.php?car=Subaru&Year=2016 which would save you from creating an html file per option (car X year = 15 files!). URLs of HTTP GET Requests can be bookmarked like Honda/2017.net. More info on this here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Comment: It works great! I do have a follow-up though. The different generated links I am working with are not the same domain. I will add several `if` statements to `document.leform.action` so that's not an issue, but how would I make the link "clean"? Clean in a sense that I would just put `document.leform.action ='www.germany.net + 'brand + '/' + year + '.html'` for `www.germany.net/brand/year.html`. If I try it now then the generated link is an extension of the site I am currently on.

Comment: use the complete url including the http part instead of just www. - like `document.leform.action ='http://www.google.de/' + brand + '/' + year + '.html';` ;)

Comment: I still seem to be getting an extension. If for an example I pick Honda 2015, then it is `document.leform.action ='http://www.japan.net + 'brand + '/' + year + '.html';`

Comment: try without syntax error ;) `document.leform.action ='http://www.japan.net/' + brand + '/' + year + '.html';`

Comment: Is it possible to have the link show up as well? So as of now, I make my selection and when I click Submit, it opens the `url`. I was wondering how I would output the generated link above the button.

Answer (score 2):

use below snippet as a boilerplate.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form>

 <input list="Cars" onchange="generateUrl()">
   <datalist id="Cars">
   <option value="Honda" selected>Honda</option>
   <option value="Mazda">Mazda</option>
   <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
   <option value="Nissan">Nissan</option>
   <option value="Subaru">Subaru</option>
   </datalist>

 <input list="Years" onchange="generateUrl()">
   <datalist id="Years">
   <option value="2017">2017</option>
   <option value="2016">2016</option>
   <option value="2015">2015</option>
   </datalist>

   <input type="reset">

</form>

<p id="generated">
 
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
function generateUrl(){
 var x = document.querySelector("[list='Cars']").value;
 var y = document.querySelector("[list='Years']").value;
 document.getElementById('generated').innerHTML = (x+y);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can grab the values of the `<datalist>` using the `onchange` event; store them in a variable somewhere, then write it out to your link.

```js
var car = '';
var year = '';

$("input[name=car-list]").on('change', function(){
    car = $(this).val();
});

$("input[name=yr-list]").on('change', function(){
    year = $(this).val();
});

$("input[name=submit]").on('click', function(){
    $("#mylink").attr('href', car + '/' + year);
    $("#mylink").html(car + '/' + year);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

<input list="Cars" name="car-list">
  <datalist id="Cars">
  <option value="Honda" selected>Honda</option>
  <option value="Mazda">Mazda</option>
  <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
  <option value="Nissan">Nissan</option>
  <option value="Subaru">Subaru</option>
  </datalist>

<input list="Years" name="yr-list">
  <datalist id="Years">
  <option value="2017">2017</option>
  <option value="2016">2016</option>
  <option value="2015">2015</option>
  </datalist>

  <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit">
  <input type="reset">

</form>

<a id="mylink" href="">My Link</a>
```